# Injection between $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$ to reals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would one go for creating an injective function between $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? I know something like $f(x)=2x+3$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but no matter what I try (Adding,removing,multiplying,diving with a natural number) I can't get it to be one to one.

Answer (score 4):

**Option:** Find an injection $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,1)$, then set $$g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R},\;(x,n)\mapsto f(x)+n.$$

Comment: I actually gave that question as a homework question a couple weeks ago (it was due last week anyway). This was what I was aiming for them to do.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Had I known, I would have joined the course...

Comment: As a student? That would have been odd. :-)

Comment: Note that the negative numbers are not in the target of $g.$

Comment: @mfl OK... But it doesn't prevent $g$ from being injective.

Comment: I am sorry. I have misread and was thinking of bijective instead of injective.

Comment: For surjectivity I would probably look at $f(x)+(-1)^n*\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$.

Answer (score 2):

A function like $f(x,n)= \arctan(x)+n*2\pi$ should do it.